# To find the no. of elements of order $7$ in a field of 8 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field of $8$ elements and $A= \{x\in F \,|\, x^7=1 \text{ and } x^k\neq 1 \text{ for all natural number $k<7$}\}$. Then the number of elements in $A$ is:

a) 1

b) 2

c) 3

d) 6

> I think, we want to find the no. of elements of order $7$ in a field of 8 elements. So we may take $F=GF(2^3)$ and as a group under multiplication ,the set of non zero elements of $GF(2^3)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_7$. how to find order of each element in $\Bbb Z_7$. (Ans:d)

Comment: Your possible set of orders is not correct.

Comment: $A$= {$x\in F$| $x^7$=1 and $x^k$$\neq$1  for all natural number $k<$ **1**} ----> $A$= {$x\in F$| $x^7$=1 and $x^k$$\neq$1  for all natural number $k<$ **7**}

Comment: Edit already made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unit group has 7 elements. The only group with 7 elements is $C_7$. 6 elements of $C_7$ have order $7$ and $1$ has order $1$.

The answer is 6.

Comment: Could u plz tell me, how could u compute the order so easily..?

Comment: @Tani which step don't you understand?

Comment: finding order of each element .

Comment: Lagrange's theorem tells us the order of every element of a group divides the order of the group itself. Now the non-zero elements of a field form a group under multiplication. If our field has order 8, the non-zero elements form a group of order 7. 7 is prime, so the only POSSIBLE orders of any of elements in the multiplicative group of our field is either 1, or 7. In a group, *only the identity* has order 1. Thus the other 6 non-zero elements of our field all have multiplicative order 7.

Comment: @DavidWheeler: Thanks...